# Unit Test For Infinite Loop

Tags: java, junit, mockito

This is my java thread run method and i want to write unit test for this method. But with infinte loop i can not do it. It would be nice anyone can help me with this.

```
 public void run() {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String line = null;
        boolean oneTime = true;
        loadDescription();
        while (true) {

            try {
                if (oneTime) {
                    System.out.println("press enter to get the console...............");
                    oneTime = false;
                }
                line = in.readLine();
                if (line != null) {
                    processInput(line);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Error occurred while processing console");
                logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    }
```

this is loadDescription() method

```
private void loadDescription() {
        BufferedReader in = null;
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = null;
        String str = null;
        try {
            stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(IConstants.MANUAL_FILE));
            str = in.readLine();
            while (str != null) {
                stringBuffer.append(str + "\n");
                str = in.readLine();
            }
            dfixDescription = stringBuffer.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        } finally {
            try {
                if (in != null) {
                    in.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }
        }
    }
```

and

```
private void processInput(String line) {
        line = line.trim();
        logger.info("Admin Message received: " + line);
        if ("?".equalsIgnoreCase(line) || "".equals(line)) {
              printDescription();
        } else if (line.toUpperCase().startsWith(AdminCommands.RELOAD)) {
            loadDescription();
            printDescription();
        } else if (line.toUpperCase().startsWith(AdminCommands.EXIT)) {
            adminManager.stopDFIXRouter();
            logger.debug("Closing Application.....");
            logger.debug("Closed.");
            System.exit(0);
        } else if (line.toUpperCase().startsWith(AdminCommands.RESET_OUT_SEQUENCE)) {
            try {
                String sessionIdentifier = line.split(",")[1].trim();
                int seqNo = Integer.parseInt((line.split(",")[2]).trim());
                adminManager.resetOutSequence(sessionIdentifier, seqNo);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }
        } else if (line.toUpperCase().startsWith(AdminCommands.RESET_IN_SEQUENCE)) {
            try {
                String sessionIdentifier = line.split(",")[1].trim();
                int seqNo = Integer.parseInt((line.split(",")[2]).trim());
                adminManager.resetInSequence(sessionIdentifier, seqNo);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }
        } else if (line.toUpperCase().startsWith(AdminCommands.CONNECT)) {
            String sessionIdentifier = line.split(",")[1].trim();
            adminManager.connectSession(sessionIdentifier);
        } else if (line.toUpperCase().startsWith(AdminCommands.DISCONNECT)) {
            String sessionIdentifier = line.split(",")[1].trim();
            adminManager.disconnectSession(sessionIdentifier);
        } else if (line.toUpperCase().startsWith(AdminCommands.ACTIVATE)) {
            adminManager.startDFIXRouter();
        } else if (line.toUpperCase().startsWith(AdminCommands.PASSIVATE)) {
            adminManager.stopDFIXRouter();
        } else if (line.toUpperCase().startsWith(AdminCommands.RUN_EOD)) {
            try {
                String sessionIdentifier = line.split(",")[1].trim();
                adminManager.runEod(sessionIdentifier);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }
        } else if (line.toUpperCase().startsWith(AdminCommands.SHOW_STATUS)) {
            adminManager.showStatus();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Usage: type ? for help");
        }
        System.out.print(">");
    }
```

and these are related methods for run method. following is my test method

```
 @Test
    public void run_activate() throws Exception{

        String data = "activate";
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes());
        System.setIn(in);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(AdminManager.class);
        PowerMockito.when(AdminManager.getInstance()).thenReturn(adminManagerTest);
        Mockito.doNothing().when(adminManagerTest).startDFIXRouter();
        dfixrtrAdminTest.run();
        Mockito.verify(adminManagerTest, Mockito.times(1)).startDFIXRouter();

    }
```

what is wrong with this. When i run test method it will not stop and i can not verify that needed methods are invoked how to handle this.

Comment: Don't post code as a picture. Post it as text in the question directly.

Comment: Also "But with infinte loop i can not do it." is a little vague. What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: One more problem of your code is that it asks for user input.

Comment: Then now is the time to refactor your code into dependency-injectable and unit-testable components.  Currently it is not.

Comment: I have added my code in my question

Comment: You missed that **minimal** part. Putting up so much code wont cut it either. And as said: your production code contains a bug - you **do NOT** want to loop infinite. And yes - you can't test code that would loop forever. But then you look into my answer and re-think what you are doing.

Comment: So in case your question gets deleted on you, and you decide to try again: focus on what **you** think your code should be doing. What it is doing right now is not making much sense.

Comment: And finally: your problem is first of all that you created *hard to test* code. It would take **hours** of reviewing it. There are zillions of things I would do differently. In case you are interested in talking about this, drop me a comment tomorrow or so.

Comment: it would be nice if you give me an idea of how to test run method.

Comment: For the record: changing the accept is fine ... but just in case: consider upvoting content you find helpful. Now that you reached that level ;-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to replace the code inside the infinite loop with a function.

You then write a unit test for that function.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously you can't test if a loop is really "infinite".

But then you can still step back and look at **all** the details this method is doing, like:

- opening a reader from which it will read
- having that special condition that ensures that "something" happens only once

In other words: as usually with unit tests, you carefully think about the different paths that your code can take (think: "white box testing"). That can tell you about test cases required to hit corner cases. On the other hand, you should also look at the *public contract* of your method (black box testing) - what are the things that you expect this method to do, without knowing about its implementation. That is how you think about your code, in order to then come up with reasonable tests.

And beyond that: your example is bogus. There shouldn't be an infinite loop here - at some point all lines will be read, and `read()` will not return anything else but null.

Comment: I posted all my code and having problem with while loop.

Answer (score 1):

[Late Answer] @IsharaD the answer of @GhostCat is good. I also faced this issue and the best way to resolve it, is to separate the execution of your logic from the thread execution. The `Runnable` class is like a wrapper where you delegate the execution of your own method. Also, it will help you make your test very easy.

You should have something like this:

Your class:

```
public class YourClass {

    public void execute() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Your runnable:

```
public class YourClassTask implements Runnable {

    private YourClass yourClass;

    public YourClassTask(YourClass yourClass) {
        this.yourClass = yourClass;
    } 

    @Override
    public void run() {
        yourClass.execute();
    }
}
```