# Infinite loop testing

Tags: python, testing, while-loop, infinite-loop

How could I test an infinite loop?
For example:

**func.py**

```
def func():
    while True:
        char = input().lower()
        if char == 'q':
            break 
        elif char.isalpha():
            print("It's not a number")
        if int(char) == #some_number
            break
        else:
            print('Try again')
```

**test.py**

```
def test_func():
    ???
```

Is there any solution for testing this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem

Comment: This will surely help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46446394/unit-test-for-infinite-loop

Comment: What exactly do you want to test? Whether the function works, or whether it is infinite?

Comment: If you are testing whether the function works, then these questions show how to test a function that takes user input: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63520890/how-to-automatically-feed-command-line-input-into-python-program https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21875141/one-python-script-giving-user-input-to-another-python-script/21875308

Comment: Stuart, I want to write tests for a function. If the value is 'a', I'll get
assert func() == "It's not a number"
If it's '65', I'll get it:
assert func() == "Try again"
If I get '50', for example, I will exit the loop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unit Test For Infinite Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46446394/unit-test-for-infinite-loop)

Comment: I see that your function gets input, validates that input, and then prints a message. When a function does so many different things, you could break it up to several separate functions that can be more easily tested individually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`unittest` to mock the user's input](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63522511/567595):

```
import builtins
from unittest.mock import patch

def func():
    while True:
        char = input().lower()
        if char == 'q':
            break 
        elif char.isalpha():
            print("It's not a number")
        if int(char) == 3:
            break
        else:
            print('Try again')

def test_func(inputs):
    with patch("builtins.input") as input_mock:
        input_mock.side_effect = inputs
        func()

test_func(["q"])
test_func(["3"])  
test_func(["4", "5", "6"])  # StopIteration error indicates this input is not sufficient for the function to return
test_func(["a", "b", "c", "q"])  # ValueError indicates a bug in the function
test_func(["4", "5", "6", "q"])  # Try again 3 times as expected
```

EDIT: You could also use `unittest` to capture the printed output and return it, so that you can check this output systematically against the expected output.

```
import builtins
from unittest.mock import patch
import io

def test_func(inputs):
    with patch("builtins.input") as input_mock, \
         patch("sys.stdout", new_callable=io.StringIO) as output_mock:
        input_mock.side_effect = inputs
        try:
            func()
        except StopIteration:
            print("FUNCTION DID NOT RETURN")
        return output_mock.getvalue().strip().split("\n")

print(test_func(["q"]) == [""]) # True
print(test_func(["4", "5", "6", "q"]) == ['Try again', 'Try again', 'Try again']) # True
```